# App engine PHP - Cron on custom domain cant work (always pointed on appspot)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron

There is a way to point the cron to the domain in use?
For example i have my cron on /example (inside my cron.yaml), this cron will run always on "all_appspot_url/cron"
If i'am on a domain, example.com, HOW can I let run cron directly on example.com/cron?

EDIT:
So, just to clarify, now I got the cron request to this host:

```
example.appspot.com
```

If I have to got the cron to another domain, from 
`example2.com` I have to manage it manually? 
**example2** is *totally different* from **example**

EDIT2: 
Ok, i have my main application on `example.appspot.com`.
Now, if i need to customize the domain, for example I have someone on `example2.com`, someone on `example3.com`, others on `example4.com` i need to run the cron "customized" for each one. 
I have to take the actual "domain", *for example i need to print example3.com if i'am on example3.com*.
I think there is some SDK function to "grab" the actually hostname with PHP, but i can't find out.

EDIT3: Maybe i just need a dispatch.yaml without needs to grab hostname? Because maybe i can route who goes on "example/url/customUrl" to my main application. *Without redirect*

Comment: OK, I thin I start to get what you want to do. Do you have one app (service to be technically correct) mapped to multiple custom domains or multiple services/apps deployed from the same codebase, each mapped to a different single custom domain?

Comment: Exactly, and I need to route each request to the specific domain, without redirecting it!
So example2.com/url and example3.com/url basically will see the same things, but they will use different domain

Comment: But which one is it: one app w/ multiple domains or multiple app-domain (1:1) pairs?

Comment: I have one main app and on it i need to have more domains connected.
So example2, example3, example4 are different domains that have to been routed on example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything (other than making sure your code doesn't assume a certain domain in the request's full URL). You should be able to send (manual) requests to the corresponding custom domain URL and they should be handled just as well.

The cron service and probably a few other GAE-specific services like task queues run "inside" the GAE infra, they have no knowledge of the custom domain mapping. Which is why the cron service makes the `GET` requests using the `appspot.com` domain.

I even suspect that may be just what's reported to your app (for compatibility reasons), but under the hood the actual implementation of the cron service *might* not even be using `appspot.com` (i.e. DNS) when making the request.

The custom domain mapping happens at the edge/outside the GAE service. It's an extra routing decision necessary only for requests coming from outside the GAE infra - to determine which GAE app should the request be directed to. Internal GAE requests do not need to waste time going through such lookup.

With this in mind I'd argue that `appspot.com` is actually the "direct" way and the custom domain is the longer path :)

And no, there isn't something you can do to change this behaviour.

Update:

To clarify, the address you're talking about is where the cron requests are sent **to**, not **from**. All cron requests (for all apps) are sent from a fixed address. From [Securing URLs for cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/cron#securing_urls_for_cron):

> Google App Engine issues Cron requests from the IP address `0.1.0.1`.

Update2:

With the same application mapped to multiple domains you don't actually need the domain detection capability you're asking about:

- if you only have one cron job configured in your application, shared by all domains, the capability is useless: you'll only get one request, detecting the domain will only give you max one answer, so you can, at most, handle one domain, the others will remain unhandled. In this case you can easily just iterate, inside that single handler, for each domains you have configured, the domain thus being already known inside each iteration
- if you have one cron job per domain configured you could simply use a different URL configuration for each domain (say `/cron/my_domain`) and you'd only need to parse the URL path to determine the domain

Comment: Question updated with more details, please check it :)

Comment: Added clarification. I suspect I'm actually missing your point: why would you need to get a cron request from another domain?